# How to store object full property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am new to JavaScript and I want to solve my problem . Actually , I have object and I am retrieving object value based on keys so here I want to store full object property ( mean with property name and it value ) .  Currently when I console object it give me result look like :

```
Laundry Room: true
Lawn: true
Swimming Pool: true
Water: true
```

when I try to console with `Object.map` method it just give `true` ( object value ) . I want to store full object property and value in variable like  `Laundry Room: true` then console that variable .

**My Code**

```
   Object.keys(data).map(key => {
      if (data[key] === true) console.log(data[key]);
    });
```

**Result with my code**

`true`

Comment: `console.log({[key]: data[key]});`

Comment: Please add what output you want

Comment: `map` needs to return a value but here returns undefined. Seems like you want `forEach` if you're just going to `console.log`. Please post the expected output and describe what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Did you try anything

Comment: @ponury-kostek it give me result `[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: what do you want as output?

Comment: @MahendraPratap  like "furnished":true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This will give you expected output:
```

```js
const data = {
          "Laundry Room": true,
          "Lawn": false,
          "Swimming Pool": true,
          "Water": true,
          "parking": 2
        };
    const features = {};
    const newData = {};
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      if (data[key] === true){
        features[key] = data[key];
      }
      if (key === "parking"){
        features["parking_space"] = data[key];
      }
      else newData[key] = data[key];
    });
    newData["features"] = JSON.stringify(features);
    console.log(newData["features"]);
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: I just updated my question and there I have mentioned `updated code` . It's my code I want to store that array in my code

Comment: why you were using map. Use forEach and you are pushing keys in newData["features"] so join will give you a string of all keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Just last question how to send this data in object form like `"{"furnished":true,"tv_lounge":true,"kitchen":true,"drawing_room":true,"laundry_room":true,"gas":true,"water":true,"electricity":true,"maintenance":true,"balcony":true,"servant_quarter":true,"dining_room":true,"parking_space":2}"`

Comment: I want to send data in object format like `{ "furnature":true,"Swimming ":true}`

Comment: Ok. You were pushing features in an array and were trying to join it. Instead you can add it to an object literal and use JSON.stringify. See the updated code and output.

Comment: what we can do for this , I am also pushing it data `   if (key === "parking"){
        features.push(data[key])
      }` . I mean I want to also include `parking` value in that object

Comment: in sample data you provided i saw parking_space count. So you want to just count the number of times parking appeared and use it's count?

Comment: actually , I want to also include parking space like `{  "furnature":true,"Swimming ":true,parking_space:5 } `

Comment: parking_space is separate field , I also want to include that in object

Comment: Updated my answer. tell me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank You so much you are best

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to log the list of keys in the object that have a value of true, you can use filter instead of map as follows:

```
let trueValues = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key] === true);
console.log(trueValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to log all the key value pair which value is only `true` you can try this 
`` Object.entries(data).map((eachValue) => { eachValue[1] && console.log(`"${eachValue[0]}":${eachValue[1]}`)}); ``
 
**Output**

```
"Laundry Room": true
"Lawn": true
"Swimming Pool": true
"Water": true
```

Comment: but it consider property and values as string "Laundry Room: true"

Comment: I want look like "furnished":true